# Problema em retornar Struct em C

Tags: c, struct, scanf, printf

Estou fazendo um programa simples em C que recebe nome,matricula e duas notas dos alunos porém ao retornar o valor digitado do struct na funçao Mostrar ele não retorna nada

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N  2

typedef struct {
  char nome[30];
  int matricula;
  float nota1;
  float nota2;
} Aluno;

void Mostrar(Aluno a) {
  printf("%s\n","teste");
  printf("nome = %s\n",a.nome);
  printf("matricula = %d\n",a.matricula);
  printf("nota = %f\n",a.nota1);
  printf("nota2 = %f\n",a.nota2);
}

int main() {
  Aluno a;
  Aluno alunos[N];
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    printf("Digite o nome do aluno");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(alunos[i].nome);

    printf("Digite a matricula do aluno");
    scanf("%d", &alunos[i].matricula);

    printf("Digite a nota 1 do aluno");
    scanf("%f", &alunos[i].nota1);

    printf("Digite a nota 2 do aluno");
    scanf("%f", &alunos[i].nota2);
  }

  Mostrar(alunos[N]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa não use a função `gets`,  gets é do mal. Prefira `scanf`.

Outra coisa você declarou `alunos` como um vetor de dois elementos, `alunos[0]` e `alunos[1]`. Só que no seu código você estava tentando exibir `alunos[N]` que é o mesmo que `alunos[2]` que não existe.

O que fiz foi trocar o `gets` por `scanf` e mostrar o valor de `alunos[0]` e `alunos[1]`.

```
    int main() {
        Aluno a;
        Aluno alunos[N];
        int i;

        for(i=0;i < N; i++) {
            printf("Digite o nome do aluno");

            // Modifiquei aqui.
            scanf("%s",&alunos[i].nome);

            printf("Digite a matricula do aluno");
            scanf("%d",&alunos[i].matricula);

            printf("Digite a nota 1 do aluno");
            scanf("%f", &alunos[i].nota1);

            printf("Digite a nota 2 do aluno");
            scanf("%f",&alunos[i].nota2);

        }

        // Modifiquei aqui.
        Mostrar(alunos[0]);
        Mostrar(alunos[1]);

        //Ou então pode usar essa sintaxe. Para usar comente as duas utimas linhas e descomente a próxima linha.
        //for(int i=0; i < N; i++) { Mostrar(alunos[i]);}

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: True, muito obrigado , poRÉM se meu vetor tivesse tamanho 10, teria que escrever 10 vezes o alunos[0],alunos[1] e etc? Ou tem outro jeito de pegar todas as posições do vetor? Porque eu tentei alunos[N] e nao consegui

Comment: Use um laço for: `for(int i=0; i < N; i++)  { Mostrar(alunos[i]);}`

Comment: o normal no caso de passar uma estrutura para uma função é usar a passagem por referência; assim, a declaração da função "Mostrar" ficaria `Mostrar(Aluno*)`, e a chamada seria `Mostrar(&alunos[0])`, ou `Mostrar(&alunos[i])`, etc

Comment: @zentrunix: Isso. Se quiser editar a resposta fique a vontade.